# boost::asio::io_service: return control to IO service's run while waiting for future

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a method that gets called via a third party from IO service. My method is supposed to return a boolean. However, I need to post another task to the same IO service, and wait for it to complete before I know the result. How can I return control to the IO loop while I wait for the other task to finish?

(I can add multiple threads, but then there could be multiple calls to my methods, and you'd still end up with a deadlock)

Call graph before:

```
<thread>    io_service               third_party    my_stuff
   |            |                        |             |
   |---run----->|                        |             |
   |            |-->some_posted_method-->|             |
   |            |                        |--callback-->|
   |            |                        |<--boolean---|
   |            |(next task)             |             |
   |            |                        |             |
```

Call graph preferred:

```
<thread>    io_service               third_party    my_stuff
   |            |                        |             |
   |---run----->|                        |             |
   |            |-->some_posted_method-->|             |
   |            |                        |--callback-->|
   |            |<----some_way_to_return_control-------|
   |            |(next task)             |             |
   |            |--------some_kind_of_resume---------->|
   |            |                        |<--boolean---|
   |            |                        |             |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Tanner Sansbury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053968/tanner-sansbury) mentioned, you can call `poll_one` from your event handler, and it will execute the available handlers.

Mind that you have to call `poll_one`, since `poll` is not guaranteed to return if new handlers keep being added. And since `poll_one` may not have a handler ready to execute yet, you may want to add a sleep to prevent busy waiting. My code ended up like this:

```
while( !syncDone ) {
    boost::system::error_code  ec;

    int handlersExecuted = ioService.poll_one(ec);
    if( ec ) {
        //Not sure what error there could be, log it
    }

    if( 0 == handlersExecuted ) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(
            std::chrono::milliseconds(10)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is a very bad idea to call `sleep_for()` even with a small timeout in an ASIO event handler. During that sleep, you are not handling events, and blocking at least one thread unnecessarily. If you need to wait for another task to get added to the task queue, use `ioService.run_one_for()` (respectively `io_context::run_one_for()` in newer versions of ASIO). If because of the logic of the other tasks, you can be 100% sure, that the other task will arrive eventually, you can even use `run_one()`.

Answer (score 1):

"third_party" should call "my_stuff" asynchronously, specify a handler that will continue as soon as result is ready, and return control to `io_service`. "third_party" is a little bit worrying here as it's possible you cannot modify it or it's not desirable.

Another approach would be to use another `io_service` instance for "my_stuff": "my_stuff" interface would be synchronous but implementation would use `io_service` in the same or another thread to accomplish its task. Never tried this but I don't see any problem from what I know about Boost.Asio.

Comment: Yes, async would be better and I opened an issue with the developer for it. There's no way to return control? What would happen if I would just call io_service.run or so?

Comment: I don't know about calling `io_service.run()` from inside another `io_service.run()`. this wouldn't work in general case (state management becomes really nasty) except such usage was intended. deserves a try or another question. btw, forgot to ask, why do you need `io_service`? it doesn't look like async IO will give any benefit in your case, so maybe you can use Asio synchronously for this particular case?

Comment: It's a TCP server, so I need async to accept the multiple connections. The slow callback is on opening a connection. So as long as there aren't too many connections opening at the same time it _could_ work...

Comment: I think that calling `io_service.run()` from inside "third_party" is synchronous anyway, so no difference in responsiveness with accepting connections synchronously

Comment: I call the run method via a thread group to start the application

Comment: @Johan This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28652055/1053968) covers details about nested calls to `io_service.run()`, but the synopsis is that one can only poll the `io_service` from a thread that is currently calling run.

Comment: That's very interesting, I will look into that. I don't really understand why it says poll isn't blocking and I can't really find any info on it. Does it starts its own thread? If not, does it use only the other threads assigned to run ioService?

Comment: because it executes only ready handlers? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll.html

Comment: poll works perfectly. If you make this into an answer, I can accept it :)