# What is the right pattern to use with asio::async_read?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

I've a project that talks to a remote system using Asio. I've encapsulated all Asio code in a class that opens a synchronous connection in the constructor then provide a public method so the user of the class can write over the socket. These methods do a synchronised `asio::write` and then call `asio::async_read`.

Now my problem:

Response time from the remote system is unknown so I need to let the user know it must wait. I'm thinking of doing this with a state machine that is initialised when the user does a `asio::write` and update it again on the callback of `asio::async_read`. This means client code would have to loop over a flag for indeterminate time while it waited for the read callback, which seems brittle to me.

Are there better mechanisms to notify calling code of a changed state? If the client code is looping will `asio::async_read`'s callback be called and the flag updated?

Comment: Most user interfaces provide some kind of message loop in the background that can update the user interface, so I would post a message into that loop from the callback handler of asio::async_read.

Comment: There is client code but no UI. Updated question.

Comment: Well, some kind of loop in your client program is required. If there is no existing loop that you can use, you have to create one. boost condition_variable can be useful to wait for the answer. use timed_wait unless you are 100% sure to receive an answer.

Comment: Turn that into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the threading model?  Is there another thread running the `io_service` while a different thread waits for `async_read` to finish?  If there are discrete threads, then using `std::future` or Asio's support for [`future`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011/futures.html) could provide a succinct and elegant solution.

Comment: It's all in the same thread.

Comment: @ruipacheco If it is all in the same thread, then blocking synchronously, such as by `std::future` or condition variables, without allowing the `io_service` event loop to make progress will not work.  Blocking within a completion handler on an asynchronous operation can be an indication of design-smell.  If this behavior is necessary, then one may need to explicitly allow the `io_service` to progress by polling it.  This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39911668/1053968) may be helpful.

Comment: @TannerSansbury - Can you explain that last comment better? I'm now reaching a point where handlers aren't called and I suspect it's because the `io_service` is blocked.

Comment: Found and fixed my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boost::condition_variable as follows:

```
//globals
boost::mutex mut;
boost::condition_variable cond;
bool waitflag = false;
bool response_available = false;



// inside async_read callback
bool waited;
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut);
    if ((waited = waitflag)) // check if client loop is waiting for us
        waitflag = false;
    response_available = true;// write also any additional data to be read by client here
}
if (waited)
    cond.notify_one(); // notify client



// inside client loop, use a short waiting time if the loop needs to perform other tasks simultaneously
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut);
    if (!response_available) {
        waitflag = true; // signal that we are waiting for callback
        cond.timed_wait(lock, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100));
    }
    if (response_available) { // check if data arrived
    }
}
```